# Is there any way to fix this python code?

Tags: python

Year10 - Year11 A453 Arithmetic Quiz-

All this to my knowledge works correctly. I am leaving this here just so there is some context.

```
file = open

def menu():
    entry = False
    while entry == False:
        print('            ***************************')
        print('            * Arithmetic Quiz Scores! *')
        print('            ***************************')
        print('')
        print('')
        print('1. Alphabetic Order (Highest)')
        print('')
        print('2. Highest - Lowest')
        print('')
        print('3. Average (Highest-Lowest)')
        print('')
        print('4. Quit')
        print('')
        choice=input('What do you want to do - 1, 2, 3, 4? ')
        if choice == '1':
            print("")
            alphabetic_order()
            entry = False
        elif choice == '2':
            print("")
            highest_lowest()
            entry = False
        elif choice == '3':
            print("")
            average()
            entry = False
        elif choice == '4':
            print("Goodbye")
            entry = True
        else:
            print("")
            print("Im Sorry But That Is Not An Option, Please Choose Again!")
            input("Press Enter!")
            print("")

def alphabetic_order():
    inputFile = open("Names.txt", 'r')
    lineList = inputFile.readlines()
    lineList.sort()
    for line in lineList:
        line = line.strip()
        parts = line.split(" - ")
        name =   parts[0]
        score1 = parts[1]
        score2 = parts[2]
        score3 = parts[3]
        alphabetical=(max(score1, score2, score3))
        print(" "+ name + "   " + alphabetical)
        print("")
    inputFile.close()
```

This is the content of the file `Names.txt`:

```
Tim - 5 - 6 - 7
Chloe - 6 - 3 - 9
Zack - 9 - 10 - 8
Bob - 7 - 4 - 6
Bo - 8 - 9 - 9
Adam - 8 - 4 - 5
Joe - 3 - 2 - 5
Zoey - 6 - 6 - 6
Larry - 7 - 3 - 3
Mary - 5 - 6 - 9
```

[FIXED] At this point the code does not sort the scores in highest to lowest it outputs most of them lowest to highest and I believe that for one of them which has a score of 10, the code thinks it is just a 1. [FIXED]

```
def highest_lowest():
inputFile = open("Names.txt", 'r')
lineList = inputFile.readlines()
lineList.sort()
for line in lineList:
    line = line.strip()
    parts = line.split(" - ")
    name =   parts[0]
    score1 = int(parts[1])
    score2 = int(parts[2])
    score3 = int(parts[3])
    total=(score1, score2, score3)
    highestlowest=sorted(total, key=int, reverse=True)
    print(" "+ name + "  " + str(highestlowest))
    print("")
inputFile.close()
```

[HELP]At this part the code is supposed to order the students based on their average (highest to lowest), however it doesn't do that.[HELP]

```
def average():
    inputFile = open("names.txt", "r")
    lineList = inputFile.readlines()
    lineList.sort()
    for line in lineList:
        line = line.strip()
        parts = line.split(" - ")
        name =   parts[0]
        score1 = parts[1]
        score2 = parts[2]
        score3 = parts[3] 
        total= int(score1) + int(score2) + int(score3)
        average_= int(total) /3
        print (" "+ name + " " + str(round(average_)))
        print("")
    inputFile.close()

menu()
```

**Could you please help me to understand why these numbers don't get sorted as I expect?** I'm sorry if this isn't how I am supposed to ask questions, I am new.

Comment: @Ocean, I think snamecharmerb was hinting that `"10" < "4"` since they are comparing as strings, and python will by default sort lowest to highest, you can reverse this order by specifying `lineList.sort(reverse=True)`

Answer (score 1):

To your question:

> Could you please help me?

I'd say, yes I can.

To the question you haven't asked:

> Why my code is not sorting the numbers as expected?

The answer is because your numbers are still strings. You need to convert them to numbers, i.e.:

```
score1 = int(parts[1])
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your code is the fact that you try to sort strings and expect the same results as with numbers.

In both your methods you load the file

```
inputFile = open("names.txt", "r")
```

Then you read the lines

```
lineList = inputFile.readlines()
```

Now you have a list containing strings. The sort algorithm compares then the strings and not the numbers.

For the average e.g. you should try to calculate the average for each person and then sort it by the average.

Greetings

Comment: How do i go about doing that?

Comment: I am not going to give you the exact code for this because this looks like a learning exercise to me. Just try to imagine what your program needs to do. First you need all the average values for each player. Then you need to sort them and finally you need to print them out in the correct order. Keep in mind that you need a link between a name and an average value so you can print out the correct average value with each name.

Comment: This is coursework, which is due in a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the difference in how strings are sorted vs integers.

It might seem surprising but it turns out to be logical to sort strings and integers in very different ways.  In particular strings are usually sorted in [**lexicographical order**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).  For example: `"ab" < "b"` and, similarly `"25" < "6"`.

In Python, you can type these in directly to see how they're interpreted:

```
"ab" < "b"
#prints True

"25" < "6"
#prints True

25 < 6
#prints False
```